# Segmentation Fault encountered while implementation of DFS using STL in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, stl, depth-first-search

Debugging of segmentation fault is one of the key issues I am facing as beginner in C++. I had tried to implement Depth First Search in Directed Graphs using C++ STL in the following lines of code (based on Steven Skienna's Algorithm Design Manual) :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>
    #include <cstdio>


    using namespace std;

    #define TREE        0       /* tree edge */
    #define BACK        1       /* back edge */
    #define CROSS       2       /* cross edge */
    #define FORWARD     3       /* forward edge */


    class Graph
    {
        int V; //no of vertices
        int time;
        list <int> *adj; //Pointer to an array containeing the adjacency list

    public:

        Graph(int V); //A constructor 
        int entry_time[] ,exit_time[] , parent[] ;
        bool processed[] , discovered[] ;
        void addEdge(int v , int w ) ; // a function to add an edge to graph 
        void DFS(int v); // print DFS transversal of the complete graph 
        void initializeGraph () ; // a function used by DFS
        void process_edge(int x , int y);
        void process_vertex_early(int x);
        void process_vertex_late(int x);
        int edge_classification(int x , int y);
    };

    Graph::Graph(int V)
    {
        this->V = V;
        adj = new list<int>[V]; //  dynamic allocation of V lists to an array named adj
    }

    void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w )
    {
        adj[v].push_back(w); //Add w to v's list
    }

    void Graph::initializeGraph ()
    {

        time = 0;

        for (int j=0;j<V;j++)
            {
                processed[j]=discovered[j] = false;
                parent[j]=-1;
            }

        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    }

    void Graph::DFS(int v)
    {   

        process_vertex_early(v);
        list <int>::iterator i  ;


        for (i=(adj[v].begin());i!=adj[v].end();++i) 
        {   cout << *i ;
            if (discovered[*i]==false)
                {
                    parent[*i] = v ;
                    process_edge(v,*i);
                    DFS(*i);
                }
            else if (processed[*i]==false)
                    process_edge(v,*i);

        }

        process_vertex_late(v);


    }

    void Graph::process_vertex_early(int v)
    {
        discovered[v] = true;
        time = time +1 ; 
        entry_time[v] = time ;
        printf("discovered vertex %d at time %d\n",v, entry_time[v]);
    }

    void Graph::process_vertex_late(int v)
    {
        time = time + 1 ;
        exit_time[v] = time; 
        processed[v] = true;
        //printf("processed vertex %d at time %d\n",v, exit_time[v]);

    } 

    int Graph::edge_classification (int x , int y )
    {
        if (parent[y]==x) return (TREE);
        if (discovered[y] && !processed[y]) return (BACK);


        //cout << " Warning : self loop " << x << y ; 
    }

    void Graph::process_edge(int x , int y)
    {   
        int type ;

        type = edge_classification(x,y);

        //if (type== BACK) cout << "Back Edge" << x << " -> " << y << endl;
        //else if (type== TREE) cout << "Tree Edge" << x << " -> " << y << endl;
        //else cout << " Not in the type " ; 

    }


    int  main()
    {
        Graph g(4);
        g.initializeGraph();
        g.addEdge(0,1);
        g.addEdge(0,2);
        g.addEdge(1,2);
        g.addEdge(2,0);
        g.addEdge(2,3);
        g.addEdge(3,1);

        cout << " Following is a DFS transversal \n " ;
        g.DFS(0);
        return 0;
    }
```

Segmentation Fault occurs after the search operation reaches a depth of one or two. I had tried applying Breadth First Search using a similar syntax which worked . Please help me in debugging this code . Thanks .

Comment: Here's what I think: `entry_time` ... are arrays of unspecified type, which are not allowed, but you are probably using gcc/g++ which allows that. I never used those, but when I change them to dynamic arrays like `adj`, there is no segmentation fault.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` instead of these non-standard empty arrays, and `std::vector<std::list<int>>` for the adjacency list?  You're using `std::list`, so why not also `std::vector`?

Comment: Here is your code using [std::vector](http://ideone.com/VP5B16)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie . Thank you so much .

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie ! I was looking at your code and I have a few doubts :
1)

Comment: @sakshamjindal If your doubt is the change of the name from `array` to `myArray`, I suggest you do the same thing.  There is a `std::array` class in C++, and on my version of Visual Studio, the `array` name clashed with `std::array`.  Try not to name your types the same as STL or standard types.  Otherwise, the code is exactly the same as yours, only that `std::vector` is used, eliminating the need for `new[]` and shortens the code by constructing the vector with the proper number of elements.  Another change is that you don't need `V` anymore -- a vector knows its own size already.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have stopped using arrays now .Yeah I noticed that I dont need `this->V = V` anymore in the constructor . In fact , when I was just trying to play with the code by using `this->V = V`  , the compiler produced an error . Moreover, I felt apprehensive of the fact that you used `resize(adj.size(),0) ` . Is it just another way of initializing values of the vectors like 'discovered'  This doubt stems from the fact that size has already been defined in constructor . Thank you.

Comment: @sakshamjindal - This would have been better: `entry_time = std::vector<int>(adj.size());` and all for other vectors.  Or this `entry_time.clear(); entry_time.resize(adj.size(),-1);`.

Answer (score 3):

Step one is to read all compiler warnings (and compile with warnings switched on).

For example:

```
   int entry_time[] ,exit_time[] , parent[] ;
```

These arrays are defined with no size - but you are putting data in them. This means you are writing outside the array boundaries which cause Undefined Behavior (such as the crashing and double-frees you are seeing). Either allocate space for these arrays like you do for `adj`, or use another container (such as `vector`) which you can resize as needed.

Also `edge_classification` doesn't always return a value - your compiler should have warned you about this.

Edit: More about `std::vector`

You can't declare your arrays to be as `entry_time[V]` because the value of `V` isn't known at compile time. You could have many different `Graph` objects with different sizes.

If you change your arrays to `std::vector` you can then allocate their size in the `Graph` constructor and let the `std::vector` class worry about allocating and freeing memory.

For example:

In the class declare `entry_time` as a `std:vector`:

```
std::vector<int> entry_time;
```

In the constructor, set the size of the `entry_time` vector.

```
entry_time.resize(V);
```

Note that you can use `V` here as a parameter to resize as this is at run-time so it now has a value.

`std::vector` has a normal array-like accessor, so you can assign values into the entries of the vector as you would an array. For example, your existing code will still work:

```
entry_time[v] = time ;
```

Comment: Hi @The Dark ! Thank you for the comment . Initially I wanted to define these variable of size V :
int entry_time[V] ,exit_time[V] , parent[V]
but the compiler gave me two of these errors

1) error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Graph::V’
             int V; //no of vertices
2)error: from this location
             int entry_time[V] ,exit_time[] , parent[] ;

Is there any way I can define these array of size V in the class Graph .

Comment: Learn to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @The Dark I allocated memory for all those five variable using 'new int [V]' and 'new bool [V]' . This worked. Thanks .

Comment: @sakshamjindal Use `std::vector` -- you're creating memory leaks by using `new[]` without using `delete[]`.  In addition, you get no runtime check of boundaries using `new[]`, while you can using `std::vector::at()`.  See my comments in the main post with a link to an example using `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you so much for making me familiar with memory leaks associated with  `new[ ]` . I have just read more about vector and will use it @The Dark the introduction to vector helps . Thanks !